# How to properly validate a model in .NET 7 using minimal API

Tags: c#, .net-core

While I know, that minimal API does not support model validation out of the box, I have seen plenty of examples of people using EndpointFilters and FluentValidation (or something similar) to validate their models. However filters are only invoked if the request object is somewhat valid already (e.g. correct types - int not in quotes, guid is a valid guid etc.).

If I have the following request object

```cs
public record CustomRequestObject(string? Identification);
```

and I call my endpoint with the following body

```json
{
    "Identification": 12
}
```

Instead of calling my custom filter, a `BadHttpRequestException` is thrown, since it can not map the json to my C# record. - My filter is called if I put quotes around the number, making it a string.

While I could catch the `BadHttpRequestException` in some custom middleware, and return the exception message, it is not very explicit in telling what is wrong with the model: `Failed to read parameter "CustomRequestObject request" from the request body as JSON`. Imagine a larger model with 10 properties, how would I as a caller figure out what went wrong?

I have created a minimal reproduction here to show the problem.

Project.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Program.cs

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapPost("/test", (CustomRequestObject request) => Results.Ok(request))
    .AddEndpointFilter(async (context, next) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Filter called!");
        return await next(context);
    });

app.Run();

public record CustomRequestObject(string? Identification);
```

I have also created some middleware that would return the error to the caller, but I am not very happy with this solution

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    try
    {
        await next(context);
    }
    catch (BadHttpRequestException ex)
    {
        var exceptionMessage = ex.Message;

        await Results.ValidationProblem(new Dictionary<string, string[]>
        {
            { "MappingError", new []
            {
                $"Some type could not be mapped correctly: {exceptionMessage}"
            }}
        }).ExecuteAsync(context);
    }
});
```

What would be the correct way to validate the incoming models, and respond with an error that is useful to the caller every time?

If the request types are all correct, I can use my filter to validate that a string is properly formatted or an integer is within the correct range, but until I get into my filter, I can not find a way to check / map the model.

Hope you can help.

Comment: why not just give API document with the caller to let them know how to transfer the request data along with the data type?

Comment: @TinyWang Sure, I am exposing a documentation page using Swashbuckle and OpenApi, but to me it feels wrong to just return a `BadRequest` without any indication about what went wrong. - Maybe it's a non-issue, and I might be overthinking things, but why would I ever spend time returning an error, if it says in the documentation a string can only have a certain length, that should be enough? I want to help the caller as much as possible, even those that skimp on reading my documentation.

Comment: @AndreasV. You can use package like FluentValidation (https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/index.html). Tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zh1ccvTFzs8. This will validate each property and return an explicit error message.

Comment: @Bandook As I wrote in my question, I have already seen multiple examples using FluentValidation, however it does not work with minimal API for model validation, as the model binding is happening before the validation has a chance to validate, which results in an error when actually trying to bind the model to a C# object.

Comment: @AndreasV. Please look at BindAsync method provided for Minimal API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/parameter-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bindasync) You can control the binding this way. The other way to think about it is to change your design pattern - think of using mediator with a pipeline for validation - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JzQuIvxIqk. Most likely a combination of both will give you a clean architecture. BUT BindAsync is what you're looking for, I believe. Let me know if you need help with implementation.

Comment: @Bandook I have played a bit with `BindAsync` now, and I would have to go through some serious hoops to bind my model manually from the Json provided in the request, since it can literally be anything. This would count against the things that are neat about minimal API. I am already using Mediator, but that validation pipeline wont help much, if the request never comes that far (denied before model binding).
If you have an approach for implementing  `BindAsync` for a record  `public record CustomRequestObject(Guid Identification)` I would be really excited to see it.

Comment: @AndreasV. The auto-binding of model does the same thing - it gets captured and then deserialized to an object (all internally). Think of BindAsync as a way to override that internal method for more control. I apologize for not fully understanding your use case - is that single endpoint expecting several different models? What is Identification - Is that a primary key for a database?

Comment: @AndreasV. Unfortunately it seems we cannot continue this over a chat as you don't have a rep of 20. That would've been easier.

Comment: @AndreasV. Can you provide a more elaborate example of your use-case?

Comment: @Bandook I have created a small but realistic [example here](https://github.com/andreasuvoss/minimal-api-validation). Imagine it being like a forum where you want to create a post in a specific category for a specific user. This is a playground example, but I created a test-suite you can run to validate that you most of the time wont even hit the filters when your model is invalid, because the binding goes wrong due to types. I hope you will take a look.

Comment: @kylemart Unfortunately not. Although I have not looked into it for a while, it might be fixed in .NET 8, I don't remember reading this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/min-api-filters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#validate-an-object-with-a-filter